# Order by collection member in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query for getting an actor, roles and movies from the example movie database in Neo4j like this:

```
MATCH (actor:Person {name:"Meg Ryan"})-[role:ACTED_IN]->(movies)
RETURN actor, collect({roles: role.roles, movies: movies}) as movies
```

It all works nice, but when I want to order the collection by movies release year, I'm encountering some issues.

I tried to do it like this:

```
MATCH (actor:Person {name:"Meg Ryan"})-[role:ACTED_IN]->(movies)
ORDER BY movies.released DESC
RETURN actor, collect({roles: role.roles, movies: movies}) as movies
```

but i get this error:

```
Invalid input 'R': expected 'p/P' (line 2, column 2)
"ORDER BY movies.released DESC"
  ^
```

How can i order the collection by the Movies release year before putting it in a collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WITH keyword befor ORDER BY to sort the results before collect:

Beware that the WITH part needs to contain all variables that are used later in the query (actor,role,movies in this case).

```
MATCH (actor:Person {name:"Meg Ryan"})-[role:ACTED_IN]->(movies)
WITH actor,role,movies 
ORDER BY movies.released DESC
RETURN actor, collect({roles: role.roles, movies: movies}) as movies
```

Similar example is given in the [documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-with.html#with-sort-results-before-using-collect-on-them).

Comment: You beat me by 10 seconds before i answered it myself :)This is correct answer, but please for future reference, edit it so it includes the "role" variable in the WITH statement, so can be used in the RETURN statement (or else an error will occur) before i mark your answer as correct. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Ah, missed that one :-) Thanks!

Comment: Missed it myself, but the Neo console didn't ;)